# TikZ: How to set width of complicated TikZ-image to \textwidth?

Tags: tikz-pgf, width, border, fbox, textwidth

I have one a bit complicated `TikZ`-image:

[image: Screenshot]

---

As you can see, I want to put one single border around this `TikZ`-image. Due to optical harmony the border should have the exactly same outside dimension like `\textwidth`.

Now I tried two different approaches to put the border around the image:

1. Put the border around the `tikzimage` in the preambel already: That puts the border very close to the content of the image what looks nice, but it has a huge margin to the left edge of `\textwidth`. In the image this is shown as the inner border.
2. Put the border around the `tikz` recall-function inside the `document`-part: That causes a very big space between the content of the image and the border, but at least the left border is fitting with the left `\textwidth`-edge. In the image this is shown as the outer border.

As you can see, none of them works fine.

How would you set the size of the image as well as the border correctly? I want to be flexible in case of later changes to the document geometry, so it should adapt to the `\textwidth` automatically.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

% Adjusts the size of the wheel:
\def\innerradius{0\textwidth}
\def\outerradius{0.15\textwidth}

\definecolor{A0}{HTML}{A4DA90}
\definecolor{B0}{HTML}{ECEB80}
\definecolor{C0}{HTML}{9D7AB3}
\definecolor{D0}{HTML}{7E8BB4}

% The main macro
\newcommand{\wheelchartwithlegend}[1]{
  % Calculate total
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}
  \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
      \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}
      \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
  }

 \fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}

    % Rotate so we start from the top
    \begin{scope}[rotate=90]

    % add coordinate to define the upper left starting point of the legend entries
    \coordinate (L-0) at (\outerradius+0mm,-\outerradius-2.5cm);

    % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the wheel
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
    \foreach [count=\i,remember=\i as \j (initially 0)] \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

          % Calculate the percent value
          % \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value/\totalnum*100}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value}
          % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

          % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
          \pgfmathparse{
             (-\midangle<180?"west":"east")
          } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
          \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle>180)}

          % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
          \fill[\colour] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
          (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;

          % Draw the data labels
          \draw  [Circle-,thin] node [append after command={(\midangle:\midradius pt) -- (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) -- (\tikzlastnode)}] at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) [xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, ,anchor=\textanchor]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}\thinspace\%};

          % add legend node
          \node [anchor=north west,text width=5cm,font=\footnotesize] (L-\i) at (L-\j.south west) {\name};
          % draw legend image
          \fill [fill=\colour] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=1mm]L-\i.north west) rectangle ++(-2mm,5mm);


          % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
          \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
      }
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
} % Closing \fbox
} % Closing \newenvironment

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}

\fbox{\wheelchartwithlegend{
    54.52/D0/{Organic (kitchen and garden waste)},
    21.23/C0/{Plastics},
    13.04/B0/{Textiles (leather, sanitary, diaper)},
    11.21/A0/{Others}
    }
}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your image is wider than `\textwidth` you'll have to work on it to adjust it to desired width. This solution won't change any image dimension (width, height, font size) unless you do it.

Another solution could be to use `standalone` class. In this case, you'll work on an independent file to produce the desired image and, later on, include it in your text with an `\includegraphics` command whit `width=\textwidth` option. In this case, the image dimensions will be scaled (also text) to fill `\textwidth`.

As an example with your MWE. Insert `wheelchartwithlegend` inside a `standalone` document. `tikz` option will crop the final result. And `tikzpicture` option `show background rectangle` will draw the desired border.

```
%File wheel.tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, backgrounds}
%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Adjusts the size of the wheel:
\def\innerradius{0\textwidth}
\def\outerradius{0.15\textwidth}

\definecolor{A0}{HTML}{A4DA90}
\definecolor{B0}{HTML}{ECEB80}
\definecolor{C0}{HTML}{9D7AB3}
\definecolor{D0}{HTML}{7E8BB4}

% The main macro
\newcommand{\wheelchartwithlegend}[1]{
  % Calculate total
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}
  \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
      \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}
      \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
  }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]

    % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}

    % Rotate so we start from the top
    \begin{scope}[rotate=90]

    % add coordinate to define the upper left starting point of the legend entries
    \coordinate (L-0) at (\outerradius+0mm,-\outerradius-2.5cm);

    % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the wheel
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
    \foreach [count=\i,remember=\i as \j (initially 0)] \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

          % Calculate the percent value
          % \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value/\totalnum*100}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value}
          % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

          % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
          \pgfmathparse{
             (-\midangle<180?"west":"east")
          } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
          \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle>180)}

          % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
          \fill[\colour] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
          (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;

          % Draw the data labels
          \draw  [Circle-,thin] node [append after command={(\midangle:\midradius pt) -- (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) -- (\tikzlastnode)}] at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) [xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, ,anchor=\textanchor]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}\thinspace\%};

          % add legend node
          \node [anchor=north west,text width=5cm,font=\footnotesize] (L-\i) at (L-\j.south west) {\name};
          % draw legend image
          \fill [fill=\colour] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=1mm]L-\i.north west) rectangle ++(-2mm,5mm);


          % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
          \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
      }
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 % Closing \fbox
} % Closing \newenvironment


\begin{document}

\wheelchartwithlegend{
    54.52/D0/{Organic (kitchen and garden waste)},
    21.23/C0/{Plastics},
    13.04/B0/{Textiles (leather, sanitary, diaper)},
    11.21/A0/{Others}
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now you can include this image in your text with `graphicx` package. First image shows its real size and the second one is adjusted to `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{wheel}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{wheel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

First of all, you have some unwanted spaces before and after your picture. This is what causes the extra distances to the right and left between the `\fbox`es. I have removed the empty rows (most of them does not matter, but just to be on the safe side) and added some `%` after rows to get rid of spaces. Then, your picture is still too wide, but since it is not too much, it can be fixed with scaling, here by `\resizebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

% Adjusts the size of the wheel:
\def\innerradius{0\textwidth}
\def\outerradius{0.15\textwidth}

\definecolor{A0}{HTML}{A4DA90}
\definecolor{B0}{HTML}{ECEB80}
\definecolor{C0}{HTML}{9D7AB3}
\definecolor{D0}{HTML}{7E8BB4}

% The main macro
\newcommand{\wheelchartwithlegend}[1]{%
  % Calculate total
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}%
  \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {%
    \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}
    \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
  }%
  \fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
      % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}
      % Rotate so we start from the top
      \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
        % add coordinate to define the upper left starting point of the legend entries
        \coordinate (L-0) at (\outerradius+0mm,-\outerradius-2.5cm);
        % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the wheel
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
        \foreach [count=\i,remember=\i as \j (initially 0)] \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}
          % Calculate the percent value
          % \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value/\totalnum*100}
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value}
          % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}
          % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
          \pgfmathparse{
            (-\midangle<180?"west":"east")
          } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
          \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle>180)}
          % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
          \fill[\colour] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
          (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;
          % Draw the data labels
          \draw  [Circle-,thin] node [append after command={(\midangle:\midradius pt) -- (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) -- (\tikzlastnode)}] at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) [xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, ,anchor=\textanchor]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}\thinspace\%};
          % add legend node
          \node [anchor=north west,text width=5cm,font=\footnotesize] (L-\i) at (L-\j.south west) {\name};
          % draw legend image
          \fill [fill=\colour] ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=1mm]L-\i.north west) rectangle ++(-2mm,5mm);
          % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
          \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
        }
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }% Closing \fbox
}% Closing \newenvironment

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \fbox{\wheelchartwithlegend{
        54.52/D0/{Organic (kitchen and garden waste)},
        21.23/C0/{Plastics},
        13.04/B0/{Textiles (leather, sanitary, diaper)},
        11.21/A0/{Others}
      }%
    }%
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice approach! Unfortunately it is only possible to choose one answer, so I chose the one with the most votings and I'm very sorry for that... :-( Your answer is a great option nevertheless!