# Fitting tikz picture to textwidth

Tags: tikz-pgf, width

I asked for help once to draw some diagrams using Tikz, the answer that suited my needs used `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1, every node/.style={scale=1.3}]` to set the enviroment, and some diagrams doesn't fit the textwidth of my document, I tried to changed the options to `[\width=\textwidth, every node/.style={\width=\textwidth}]` but I get the following error

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/width', to which you passed '\textwidth ', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...th, every node/.style={width=\textwidth}]
```

even though I get a PDF with the desired output

What is the right way to do what I stated before?

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
    %bigger margins than usual
    \areaset{336pt}{705pt}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usetikzlibrary{automata,calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}
        \tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}]
    \tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,decoration={markings,  
        mark connection node=dmp,
        mark=at position 0.5 with 
        {
            \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
            \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
        }
    }, decorate]
    \tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.75cm,minimum height=0.3cm,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1.3}]

\node [draw, outer sep=0pt, thick] (M) [minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,yshift=-1cm] {$\mathrm{m}$};

\node (ground) [ground,anchor=north,yshift=3.3cm,minimum width=4cm,xshift=0cm] at (M.north) {};
\node [outer sep=0pt, thick] (ground2) [minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, yshift =3cm] {};

\draw (ground.south east) -- (ground.south west);


\draw [spring] (ground2.south) -- (M.north) node [midway,left] {$\mathrm{k}$};

\draw [-latex,ultra thick] (M.north west) ++ (-0.5cm, 0.0cm) -- +(0cm,-1cm);
\draw [dashed] (M.north west) ++ (0cm, 0cm) -- +(-0.8cm,0cm);
\node (y1) at (M.north west) [xshift = -0.7cm, yshift = -0.8cm] {$x$};

\draw [dashed] (M.north west) ++ (-0.8cm, 0.5cm) -- +(14cm,0cm);
\node (y2) at (M.north west) [align=center,xshift = -0.8cm, yshift = 0.4cm] {Posición\\original};



\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

> I must say that I pretend to use this diagram inside a figure
>   enviroment

Comment: Please provide a MWE that can reproduce your problem. This way nobody can help you except of some general answers like tjhese here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/correctly-scaling-a-tikzpicture

Comment: from your fragments is difficult to figured out how we can help you. the simplest is include image as pdf graphics like `includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}`

Comment: `\width=\textwidth` would be wrong as tikzkey. `width=\textwidth` would be right, but AFAIK it doesn't has a `width` key.

Comment: I´ve updated my question with a MWE

Comment: related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411671/tikz-how-to-set-width-of-complicated-tikz-image-to-textwidth/411680#411680

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `adjustbox` package to scale any content:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[....]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
```

This scales the tikzpicture as box, so everything including the text.

Comment: could I put the adjustbox enviroment inside a figure enviroment?

Comment: @PaulLara: Yes. You can place basically everything inside a `figure` environment (except other floats), as it is just a floating container.

Comment: A better option is probably the `tikzscale` package @PaulLara.

Answer (score 0):

"cfr" suggested the `tikzscale` package in a comment of the other answer.  It took me a while to figure out how to use this, so here's a summary. [Documentation here](https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzscale/tikzscale.pdf)

1. Add `\usepackage{tikzscale}` to the preamble.
2. Move your `tikzpicture` environment (including `\begin{tikzpicture}[...]`) into a seperate `*.tikz` file (e.g. `diagram.tikz`).
3. Use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{diagram.tikz}`

### Example:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                         
\usepackage[showframe,nomarginpar]{geometry}                                    
\usepackage{tikz}                                                               
\usepackage{tikzscale}                                                          
                                                                                
\begin{document}

Inline Tikzpicture:

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.7,xscale=\textwidth/2cm]                  
  \draw [color=blue] plot[domain=0:2,variable=\x,samples=51,smooth] (\x,{sin(deg(\x*pi))}) ;
  \draw [color=red!30] plot[domain=0:2,variable=\x,samples=51,smooth] (\x,{-1.0*sin(deg(\x*pi))}) ;
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);                                                     
  \coordinate (B) at (2,0);                                                     
  \draw (A) node {\textbullet} -- (1,0) node[above] {A} (1,0) node {\textbullet} -- (B) node {\textbullet};
\end{tikzpicture}                                                               

Using tikzscale:

\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{diagram.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Then `diagram.tikz` contains:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.1]
  \draw [color=blue] plot[domain=0:2,variable=\x,samples=51,smooth] (\x,{sin(deg(\x*pi))}) ;
  \draw [color=red!30] plot[domain=0:2,variable=\x,samples=51,smooth] (\x,{-1.0*sin(deg(\x*pi))}) ;
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
  \draw (A) node {\textbullet} -- (1,0) node[above] {A} (1,0) node {\textbullet} -- (B) node {\textbullet};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result:
[image]

A few note:

- You cannot set both `[width=...,height=...]`.  Only one.  That's a limitation.  I am using `\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=...]` to overcome that.
- You can use any file extension, but if you use any of .tikz,.TIKZ,.TikZ,.pgf,.PGF, then you don't need to include it in the `\includegraphics` statement.