# Tikz: incomplete \iffalse error with pgfmathparse

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, babel, spanish

I'm trying to create a pie chart like this one ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411671/tikz-how-to-set-width-of-complicated-tikz-image-to-textwidth)), but when I use the code I get an error with this code:

```
 \pgfmathparse{(-\midangle<180?"west":"east")
        } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle>180)}
```

the error says:

> Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 269"

I have found that the error is because the conditional inside, but I don't know how to achieve that that in another way. The code that I used is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows, backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \def\innerradius{2cm}
    \def\outerradius{4cm}

    \newcommand{\wheelchart}[1]{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}
        \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
            \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}
            \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
        }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}
%
\begin{scope}[rotate=90]
%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
      \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value/\totalnum*100}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}
            \pgfmathparse{(-\midangle<180?"west":"east")}  \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle>180)}
            \fill[\colour] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
            (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;         
            \draw  [*-,thin] node [append after command={(\midangle:\midradius pt+5ex) -- (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) -- (\tikzlastnode)}] at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) [xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, ,anchor=\textanchor]{\textbf{\large\name: \pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}\%}};  
            \draw node [text=white, font=\sffamily,align=center] at (\midangle:{\innerradius+\wheelwidth/2-1ex}) {\Large{\pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}\%}};
            \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
        }
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\wheelchart{35.4/orange/No votaron, 64.6/yellow/Votaron}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what you are doing because we cannot reproduce your problem from the code that you have given us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), it is difficult to know where your problem is. However, the code below does something close to what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\foreach \midangle in {0,10,20,...,360} {
   \ifnum\midangle<180
     \def\textanchor{west}\def\labelshiftdir{1}
  \else
     \def\textanchor{east}\def\labelshiftdir{-1}
  \fi
  angle=\midangle, anchor=\textanchor, shift=\labelshiftdir.

}

\end{document}
```

The output contains the lines:

[image]

Btw, if you really do want to use `\pgrmathparse` for this then instead of

```
\pgfmathparse{(-\midangle<180?"west":"east")} \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
```

you should use

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\textanchor{(-\midangle<180?"west":"east")}
```

**EDIT**

Looking at your expanded code, and the comments below, the problem actually seems to be with the variable names that you use in your `\foreach` loops:

```
\foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} { ... }
```

Note that `\value` is a "standard LaTeX command" and I think that `\name` is too. (Colour is probably safe due to the American corruption of the *English* language.) It is best to avoid existing LaTeX variable/macro names in such loops.

I am not sure which of these variable names caused your problem, or exactly what caused the conflict when using babel, but if I change these variable names then the following code compiles:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows, backgrounds}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\def\innerradius{2cm}
\def\outerradius{4cm}

\newcommand{\wheelchart}[1]{
    \def\totalnum{0}
    \foreach \val/\col/\nam in {#1} {
    \typeout{val=\val, col=\col, nam=\nam.}
        \pgfmathparse{\val+\totalnum}
        \typeout{\totalnum -> \pgfmathresult.}
        \xdef\totalnum{\pgfmathresult}
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}
      %
      \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
      %
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
      \foreach \val/\col/\nam in {#1} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \val/\totalnum*360}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\val/\totalnum*100}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}
            \pgfmathparse{(-\midangle<180?"west":"east")}
            \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle>180)}
            \fill[\col] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
            (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;
            \draw  [*-,thin] node [append after command={(\midangle:\midradius pt+5ex) -- (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) -- (\tikzlastnode)}] at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) [xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, ,anchor=\textanchor]{\textbf{\large\nam: \pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}\%}};
            \draw node [text=white, font=\sffamily,align=center] at (\midangle:{\innerradius+\wheelwidth/2-1ex}) {\Large{\pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}\%}};
            \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
        }
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

    \wheelchart{35.4/orange/No votaron, 64.6/yellow/Votaron}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Just wondering if you want to tell the OP about the `\pgfkeysalso` trick that allows one to add these things to a style.

Comment: @marmot Um, you want to tell me about the `\pgfkeysalso` trick? I'm not sure that I know it.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the answers!! but now I replace the problematic code with the `\ifnum\midangle<180` statement and I got a new error: "Missing = inserted for \ifnum. ...4/orange/No votaron, 64.6/yellow/Votaron}" and when I used  `\pgfmathsetmacro\textanchor{(-\midangle<180?"west":"east")} ` code I got the same error than before ("Incomplete \iffalse; all ..."

Comment: @TamaraVejar So the problem is being caused by something else. When I compile the new code that you have posted in your question the error that I get is `Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind '*'`, which is caused by the `\draw  [*-,thin]`. If I change this your code works fine.

Comment: @Andrew I made a mistake in the tikz's libraries declarations (the correct library was "arrow"). I checked the full code and it's looks like that the problem is with the spanish package (`\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`). If a have to use that package, there is nothing that I can do?

Comment: @TamaraVejar The problem seems to be caused by the variable names that you are using in your `\foreach` loops. See my edit.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you so much, that solved my problem. Regards!